# Sqlite sync and async together

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, sqlite-net

Is it good practice to use sqlite sync and async together.

Example i need on create method to use sqlite sync but in other thread to update another table async.

```
public class DatabaseHelper
    {
        private static SQLiteConnection sqlConnection;
        private static SQLiteAsyncConnection sqlConnectionAsync;
        public static SQLiteConnection db()
        {
            if(sqlConnection == null)
                sqlConnection = new SQLiteConnection(Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "student.db3"));
                               
            return sqlConnection;
        }
        public static SQLiteAsyncConnection dbAsync()
        {
            if (sqlConnectionAsync == null)
                sqlConnectionAsync = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "student.db3"));
           
            return sqlConnectionAsync;
        }
    }
```

OnCreate Method

```
datasource= DatabaseHelper.db().Table<Items>();
await DatabaseHelper.dbAsync().DeleteAll<Customers>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is safe, yes. As long as separate connections are used for concurrent access, then you can use synchronous or asynchronous APIs.

There's another question you didn't ask: is it useful? The last time I checked, SQLite database drivers are synchronous-only, and the "asynchronous" APIs actually run synchronously. They'll work just fine; they just may not unblock the UI, and you may need to use `Task.Run` to throw the work on a background thread even for asynchronous APIs.

Comment: Thank you Stephen!! You are my Mentor ( i have read almost everything about your work in async methods and tasks)!! So what you actually say is that:                                               
                                                                                                                                            
    await Task.Run(() =>  customers = DatabaseHelper.db().Table<Customers>());                     
 is the same with:   customers = await DatabaseHelper.dbAsync().Table<Customers>();  Right?

Comment: @George: I'm saying that - specifically for the SQLite provider - if you're on a UI thread, you may need to use `Task.Run` regardless of whether you're using synchronous or asynchronous APIs.

Comment: Thank you Stephen. Is it wrong to use `Task.Run` with syncronous sqlite api?

Comment: @George: Not if you're calling it from a UI thread.

Comment: Is it the same if i am calling `Task.Run` and sync api from ui with SQLiteAsyncConnection?

Comment: @George: Yes, that may be necessary.

Comment: Thank you Stephen!! I will propably stick with Task.Run, cause i want to keep one single instance of sqlite. I am not sure if new version of sqlite can handle multiple access from different threads, or i need to create a lock method for be more safe.